# How can we pass array to SQL server stored procedure using JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to call sql server stored procedure by passing array_list.

```
String[][] array1=new String[2][2];
array1[0][0]="a";
array1[0][1]="b";
array1[1][0]="c";
array1[1][1]="d";
String name="TEST";
String SPsql="EXEC SP_name ?,?,?";
PreparedStatement stmt=con.preparedStatement(SPsql);
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setArray(2,array1);
```

The last line is giving error. not able set array there.
I tried with list also but no use.

Comment: You need to use a `CallableStatement` for calling stored procedures. Please share the signature for the procedure.

Comment: Maybe the JDBC driver you're using doesn't support passing arrays, so you should find another way to pass the parameters.

Comment: Could you please let me know, What is the other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to pass comma separated string instead of array and then use it in query.